# Can't play local audio mp3 file with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift

I want to download and play the sound from Google Translate (Text to Speech).

The mp3 file's downloaded successfull. I tried to play it with AVAudioPlayer, but there's no sound on both simulator and my real iPhone

I use XCode 10.2.1, Swift 5. Test on simulator (XSMax) and iPhone XSMax

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class TextToSpeechGoogleTranslate: AVAudioPlayer, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
  var player: AVAudioPlayer?

  func speak() {
    let fileURL = URL(string: "https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&client=tw-ob&tl=vi&q=Hello" )!

    let documentsUrl:URL =  (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL?)!
    let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("voice.mp3")

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

    let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL)

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {

            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
            }

            do {
                try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationFileUrl)
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                print(destinationFileUrl)

                do {
                    self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: destinationFileUrl)
                    self.player!.delegate = self
                    self.player!.prepareToPlay()
                    self.player!.volume = 1.0
                    self.player!.play()

                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                catch {
                    print("AVAudioPlayer init failed")
                }


            } catch (let writeError) {
                print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription as Any);
        }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
 }
```

Output:
Successfully downloaded. Status code: 200
file:///Users/macbook/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F43F9B03-674C-4EE1-8CAD-01B5145868DE/data/Containers/Data/Application/6D1A3310-386D-4706-9F1E-DFF536B2A43F/Documents/voice.mp3

I played that file in Finder. It's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code and it seems to work fine. Maybe the problem is in how you create the `TextToSpeechGoogleTranslate` object and call `speak()` on it. For example, here is what I tried:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var test: TextToSpeechGoogleTranslate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        test = TextToSpeechGoogleTranslate()
        test!.speak()
    }
}
```

If that doesn't help, can you post some code showing how you call this method?

Comment: Thanks so much. I try your code and it worked like a charm. Can you explain why my code is fail:

`class ViewController: UIViewController { override func viewDidLoad() {  super.viewDidLoad()  let test = TextToSpeechGoogleTranslate()  test.speak()  } }`

Comment: Good, glad I could help. The problem with your code is that the `test` instance is deallocated straight away. In my version, I keep a reference around (outside `viewDidLoad`), thus `test` will get deallocated together with `ViewController`, and not right after `viewDidLoad` like in your version!

Answer (score 0):

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

```
var audioPlayer = TextToSpeechGoogleTranslate()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    audioPlayer.delegate = self
    audioPlayer!.speak()
}
```

}

1) create instance of your class
2) Confirm it's delegate
3) call your function after you received your data
4) while testing from device, don't forget to turn off silence mode (volume up)